# What is the size (diameter) of the SARS-CoV-2 virus?

Tags: virology, coronavirus

You can easily find a lot of [pictures](https://www.flickr.com/photos/niaid/albums/72157712914621487) of the `SARS-CoV-2` virus. But although it should be trivial for an electron microscope to measure the size, I am not able to find accurate size information.

**What is the size (diameter) of the SARS-CoV-2 virus?**
(Why does some virus particles seem to have a different size?)

Comment: http://virology-online.com/viruses/CORZA4.htm.

Comment: Although your question is straightforward, it would be great if you could explain why this information is useful to you.

Comment: @WYSIWYG As a researcher I'm sure you can think of at least 5 reasons, but we can probably invent another 100. But I find your request irrelevant to the question, especially in the light as 2 people have already voted for closing it. So please contact me elsewhere in case you'd like to know more.

Comment: @not2qubit It is not for my personal query. Supporting the question with a rationale helps other readers understand the post better. Since our aim here is not simply help people with their specific queries but make a repository of useful information, it is always good to have some background in the posts.

Comment: It would be far more interesting to know on what grounds people are close-voting (more or less) every question I have on this SE? Apparently the common courtesy of at least explaining why they down-vote or close-vote seem completely lacking here... The perfect way to alienate just about every new user you have here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Electron micrographs of negative-stained 2019-nCoV particles were generally spherical with some pleomorphism (Figure 3). Diameter varied from about 60 to 140 nm. Virus particles had quite distinctive spikes, about 9 to 12 nm, and gave virions the appearance of a solar corona.

--[A Novel Coronavirus from Patients with Pneumonia in China, 2019](https://www.nejm.org/doi/10.1056/NEJMoa2001017)

Figure 3 from that article:

[image]

Comment: [Does a virus have a well defined shape?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/91031/27918) links to your answer, any thoughts?